# Ubuntu 18.04 RANDOM freezes

Tags: 18.04, kernel

My ubuntu 18.04 freezes completely, keyboard, mouse, HDD stops completely.
This happens from from time to time, in a week I would get around 2-3 freezes, not that harsh and as a developer my IDE autosaves, so no known loss of info (yet..)

I tried the `/var/log` to hunt for the culprit, with no success.

From googling and understanding **this is a vast issue in Ubuntu 18.04** with no viable solution yet, I thought to maybe post a question here and see if anyone has had any success solving this.

BTW my generic kernel is: `5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`